# Type Error: Int object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an error with my code when I try to run it.

**CODE**

```
print("Operations: \n1. Addition \n2. Subtraction \n3: Multiplication \n4. Division")
print("^ Operation 'ID' please enter the id of your choice")
choice = input()
num1 = input("Enter your first number: ")
num2 = input("Enter your second number: ")
def addition(num1, num2):
    num1
    num2
    ans = num1 + num2
    print('Your answer is %s') %(ans)
def subtraction(num1, num2):
    num1
    num2
    ans = num1 - num2
    print('Your answer is %s') %(ans)
def multiply(num1, num2):
    num1
    num2
    ans = num1 * num2
    print('Your answer is %s') %(ans)
def division(num1, num2):
    num1
    num2
    ans = num1 / num2
    print('Your answer is %s') %(ans)
if choice == "1":
    addition
elif choice == "2":
    subtraction
elif choice == "3":
    multiply
elif choice == "4":
    division
else:
    print("Invalid Input")
```

Everything works until python is called to print the answer.

I am aware of the possible duplicates but none of the code provided there works.

Comment: I am also aware of the other ways to write a calculator app but I am planning of expanding its features so I need to have "def's"

Comment: Also using xfce 14.04 on a samsung chromebook sir 3 if it matters.

Comment: `if choice == "1":` try this

Comment: @vks +1 thank you, but now I have another problem its is prompting me to invalid input instead of showing me the answer

Comment: Your code has many problems. I suggest the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/index.html).

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 M bad I just fixed up the little mistakes other than that I still haven't found a ligament answer.

Comment: @AtPython do `print(choice,type(choice))`

Comment: @vks I do beg your pardon, I'm sorry I may seem very new (Om only 13) but where in my code do I put that. Also feel free to post what you think is the right answer I will be happy enough to accept it if it works.

Comment: @AtPython just before the line `if choice == "1":` and tell the output of it

Comment: It doesn't matter how old you are; all that matters is that you learn how the language works so that you can get things done. The official tutorial really is quite clear, with lots of examples. I still refer to it regularly.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Well, thank you for that advise. I really have been feeling that even once I properly learn this language my age would be a factor in which people would think of me as a lesser programmer.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 *Sigh* nothing seems to be working!

Comment: Nope, your age wouldn't be a factor. All we care about are the pointless `num1`, etc. statements, the incorrect string formatting, the lack of `int()` or `float()` calls, and the pointless `addition`, etc. statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ironically, this has ended up with me writing an answer to my own question with admittedly some help from @ Vignesh Kalai, although hid code was a little off. So before anything else I will address the changes to my code.

Firstly, instead of defining every operation I have linked than with the choice of their "ID"'s.

Secondly, I am using "" + str(x) to print the answers out instead of the admittedly bad idea of using %s.

**REVISED CODE**

```
    choice = int(input("Operations: \n1. Addition \n2. Subtraction \n3: Multiplication \n4. Division\n^ Operation 'ID' please enter the id of your choice\n"))
num1 = int(input("Enter your first number: "))
num2 = int(input("Enter your second number: "))
if choice == 1: #Addition
    num1
    num2
    ans = num1 + num2
    print("Your answer is " + str(ans))
elif choice == 2: #Subtraction
    num1
    num2
    ans = num1 - num2
    print("Your answer is " + str(ans))
elif choice == 3: #Miltiplication
    num1
    num2
    ans = num1 * num2
    print("Your answer is " + str(ans))
elif choice == 4: #Division
    num1
    num2
    ans = float(num1) / float(num2)
    print("Your answer is " + str(ans))
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is due to this

```
if choice == 1():
```

Where as it should be

```
if choice == 1:
```

And you have to convert num1 and num2 to integer types

And you should call the function just not declare them that is

```
if choice == 1:
    addition(num1, num2)
```

And you have to do this for other things

And after doing all the changes your program would look like this

```
print("Operations: \n1. Addition \n2. Subtraction \n3: Multiplication \n4. Division")
print("^ Operation 'ID' please enter the id of your choice")
choice = int(input())
num1 = int(input("Enter your first number: "))
num2 = int(input("Enter your second number: "))
def addition(num1, num2):
    ans = num1 + num2
    print('Your answer is %s') %(ans)
def subtraction(num1, num2):
    ans = num1 - num2
    print('Your answer is %s') %(ans)
def multiply(num1, num2):
    ans = num1 * num2
    print('Your answer is %s') %(ans)
def division(num1, num2):
    ans = num1 / num2
    print('Your answer is %s') %(ans)
if choice == 1:
    addition(num1,num2)
elif choice == 2:
    subtraction(num1,num2)
elif choice == 3:
    multiply(num1,num2)
elif choice == 4:
    division(num1,num2)
else:
    print("Invalid Input")
```

**My changes would be:**

```
choice = int(input("Operations: \n1. Addition \n2. Subtraction \n3: Multiplication \n4. Division\n^ Operation 'ID' please enter the id of your choice\n"))
num1 = int(input("Enter your first number: "))
num2 = int(input("Enter your second number: "))
ans=None
if choice == 1:
    ans = num1 + num2
elif choice == 2:
    ans = num1 - num2
elif choice == 3:
    ans = num1 * num2
elif choice == 4:
    ans = float(num1) / num2
if  ans:
    print('Your answer is %s') %(ans)
else:
    print("Invalid Input")
```

Comment: No sorry, that does not help

Comment: @Vingesh Kalal closest I have gotten but it just prompts invalid input where the answer should be.

Comment: @AtPython at what input did it say that

Comment: @Vingesh Kalai It wasn't me

Comment: I am not asking you I am asking the one who down voted

Comment: @Vingesh Kalai Yes, but with some modifications

Comment: @AtPython you could paste your code and accept it :)

Comment: @Vingesh Kalai, I could but yet again that would kind of be giving you one, because I only used your code as a base, there were stll many errors... but I shall think of replacing the code...

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in the lines -

```
if choice == 1():
    addition
elif choice == 2():
    subtraction
elif choice == 3():
    multiply
elif choice == 4():
    division
```

I have no idea what you want `1()` to do, seems like a typo. Also you should be calling the functions `addition` , etc , like - `addition(num1, num2)` .

And `choice` is `string` not int . And you should convert `num1` and `num2` to int.

More issues in your code -

1. Why are you doing - `num1` and `num2` in your functions , it does not do anything, you can remove the first two lines of each function.
2. Your print function in wrong, in Python 3.x , the `%(ans)` should be inside the function, not outside it.

Code -

```
num1 = int(input("Enter your first number: "))
num2 = int(input("Enter your second number: "))
def addition(num1, num2):
    ans = num1 + num2
    print('Your answer is %s' %(ans))
def subtraction(num1, num2):
    ans = num1 - num2
    print('Your answer is %s' %(ans))
def multiply(num1, num2):
    ans = num1 * num2
    print('Your answer is %s' %(ans))
def division(num1, num2):
    ans = num1 / num2
    print('Your answer is %s' %(ans))
if choice == '1':
    addition(num1, num2)
elif choice == '2':
    subtraction(num1, num2)
elif choice == '3':
    multiply(num1, num2)
elif choice == '4':
    division(num1, num2)
```

Comment: This code prompts me with the errors listed: Unsupported operand types and multiple syntax errors in the division and subtraction definitions? although I see no errors in syntax

Comment: @AtPython Yea seems like there are more issues in your code, check the latest update.

Answer (score 0):

The error with your current code is just with the brackets in your print statements. if instead of having %ans outside of the print statement, the code works when it is like this

```
print('Your answer is %s' %ans)
```

A neater version of the same code you just wrote looks like this

```python
print("Operations: \n1. Addition \n2. Subtraction \n3: Multiplication \n4. Division")
print("^ Operation 'ID' please enter the id of your choice")
choice = int(input())
num1 = int(input("Enter your first number: "))
num2 = int(input("Enter your second number: "))
def addition(num1, num2):
    return num1+num2
def subtraction(num1, num2):
    return num1-num2
def multiply(num1, num2):
    return num1*num2
def division(num1, num2):
    return num1/num2
if choice == 1:
    ans = addition(num1,num2)
elif choice == 2:
    ans = subtraction(num1,num2)
elif choice == 3:
    ans = multiply(num1,num2)
elif choice == 4:
    ans = division(num1,num2)
else:
    print("Invalid Input")
if choice in range(4):
    print('Your answer is %s' %ans)
```